# Custom subplot & colorbar placement in matplotlib (multipanel figure)

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, subplot, colorbar

I'm working on a reasonably complicated 9-panel figure in matplotlib. I want the top two subplots in each column (i.e. (00,10), (01,11) and (02,12)) to have a shared x-axis with no vertical whitespace and a shared vertical right-side colorbar spanning the height of both subplots. I want the bottom subplot (i.e. (20),(21), and (22)) in each column to be separated from those above it by a reasonable amount of whitespace, and I want each of these to have their own horizontal colorbar on the bottom. I also need every subplot image to have the same size and aspect ratio. I think I've gotten close with GridSpec (see code and plot below), but I'm not quite there. Does anyone know how to do this? Thanks!

[image: example image - what I have now]

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import make_axes_locatable
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec
from matplotlib import cm
from numpy.random import randn

gs = gridspec.GridSpec(3, 3, wspace=0.0)
m = 0
data = np.clip(randn(10, 10), -1, 1)

for i in range(0, 3, 1):
    for j in range(0, 3, 1):
        fig = plt.gcf()
        ax = plt.subplot(gs[i:i+1, j:j+1])
        im = ax.imshow(data, cmap=cm.viridis, vmin=-1,vmax=1)
        ax.text(5,5,str(i) + str(j),fontweight="bold")
        ax.set(yticklabels=[])
        ax.set(xticklabels=[])
        divider = make_axes_locatable(ax)
        if (i==2):
            cax = divider.append_axes('bottom', size='5%', pad=0.05)
            cbar = fig.colorbar(im, cax, ticks=[-1, 0, 1],orientation='horizontal')
        else:
            cax = divider.append_axes('right', size='5%', pad=0.05)
            cbar = fig.colorbar(im, cax, ticks=[-1, 0, 1],orientation='vertical')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

I got something pretty close with subfigures... Still, the spacing isn't quite right and I get bad image aspect ratios when I try to use a horizontal colorbar on the bottom axes.[image]

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import make_axes_locatable
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec
from matplotlib import cm
from numpy.random import randn

data = np.clip(randn(10, 10), -1, 1)

# gridspec inside gridspec
fig = plt.figure(constrained_layout=True, figsize=(8, 6))
fig.subplots_adjust(hspace=0.0,wspace=0.5)
subfigs = fig.subfigures(2, 3, wspace=0.5, height_ratios=[2, 1])

# left column
axsTopLeft = subfigs[0][0].subplots(2, 1, sharey=True)
im00t = axsTopLeft[0].imshow(data)
im00b = axsTopLeft[1].imshow(data)
subfigs[0][0].set_facecolor('0.85')
fig.colorbar(im00t,ax=axsTopLeft[0:])
axsBottomLeft = subfigs[1][0].subplots(1, 1, sharey=True)
im10 = axsBottomLeft.imshow(data)
fig.colorbar(im10,ax=axsBottomLeft,aspect=10)
subfigs[1][0].set_facecolor('0.75')

# middle column
axsTopMid = subfigs[0][1].subplots(2, 1, sharey=True)
im01t = axsTopMid[0].imshow(data)
im01b = axsTopMid[1].imshow(data)
subfigs[0][1].set_facecolor('0.85')
fig.colorbar(im00t,ax=axsTopMid[0:])
axsBottomMid = subfigs[1][1].subplots(1, 1, sharey=True)
im11 = axsBottomMid.imshow(data)
fig.colorbar(im11,ax=axsBottomMid,aspect=10)
subfigs[1][1].set_facecolor('0.75')

# right column
axsTopRight = subfigs[0][2].subplots(2, 1, sharey=True)
im02t = axsTopRight[0].imshow(data)
im02b = axsTopRight[1].imshow(data)
subfigs[0][2].set_facecolor('0.85')
fig.colorbar(im02t,ax=axsTopRight[0:])
axsBottomRight = subfigs[1][2].subplots(1, 1, sharey=True)
im12 = axsBottomRight.imshow(data)
fig.colorbar(im12,ax=axsBottomRight,aspect=10)
subfigs[1][2].set_facecolor('0.75')

plt.show()
```